# Jquery Notification on Ajax POST Success

Tags: forms, jquery, post, notifications

I have an issue with a some of the jQuery notifications I have created to trigger based on information echo'd from a PHP file after a user submits a sign up HTML form via AJAX. The notifications for errors work, but not for a successful post to the database. I know that the success notification should show because the data is validated and written to the database and AJAX post is successful. However the success notification does not want to work. What could be the reason for this technicality?

I have the following set up:

**signup.html** (contains the following ajax within the page*):

```
function registerUser(formKey) {
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"engine/new_user.php",
    data: $("#"+formKey).serialize(),
    cache:false,
    success: function(data) {

        if(data == -3){
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
            $("#user-exists-notification").fadeIn(1000);
            }
        if(data == -4){
            $("#account-created").fadeIn(1000);
            }
        if(data == -1){
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
            $("#fields-complete-notification").delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);
            }
        if(data == -2){
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
            $("#pw-confirm-notification").delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);
            }
    },
    error: function(data) {

    }
});
}
```

**new_user.php**

```
 require("register-classes.php");

 $register=new Register($_POST['fname'], $_POST['lname'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['sex'], $_POST['birthdate'], $_POST['phone'], $_POST['country'], $_POST['alias'], $_POST['handle'], $_POST["password"], $_POST["cpassword"], $_POST['network']);

if($register->checkFields()== false){

     echo -1;

 } else if($register->confirmPasswords()== false){

     echo -2;
 }else if($register->registerUser()!=false){


     echo -4;
 } else if($register->registerUser()==false){
     echo -3;
 }


and register-classes.php (which contains classes for processing sign up form)

    class Register {

        public function __construct($fname, $lname, $mail, $sex,
        $birthday, $phonenumber, $regCountry, $alias, $username,
        $password, $conf_password, $network_site) {

            //Copy Constructor
            $this->site=$network_site;
            $this->firstname=$fname;
            $this->lastname=$lname;
            $this->email=$mail;
            $this->sex=$sex;
            $this->birthdate=$birthday;
            $this->phone=$phonenumber;
            $this->country=$regCountry;
            $this->displayname=$alias;
            $this->handle=$username;
            $this->salt="a2cflux9e8g7ds6ggty589498j8jko007876j89j8j7";
            $this->password=crypt($this->salt.$password);
            $this->joindate=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $this->confirm_password1=$password;
            $this->confirm_password2=$conf_password;

        }

        public function registerUser(){

            $database=new Database();
            $database->getConnection();
            $database->startConnection();

            //Check database to insure user and email address is not already in the system.                     
            $checkUsers= mysql_query("SELECT network_users.network_id
            FROM network_users, network_profile
            WHERE network_users.handle = '$this->handle'
            OR network_profile.email = '$this->email'");

            $numRecords= mysql_num_rows($checkUsers);

            if($numRecords == 0){

                $addUser= mysql_query("INSERT INTO network_users(handle, password, date_created, parent_network, site_created, active, account_type, del)
                values('$this->handle', '$this->password', '$this->joindate',' fenetwork', 'network', 'active', 'standard', 'F')") or die(mysql_error());

                $networkId=mysql_insert_id();

                $addProfile= mysql_query("INSERT INTO network_profile(network_id, first_name, last_name, email, sex, birthdate, phone, country, display_name, del)
                values('$networkId', '$this->firstname', '$this->lastname', '$this->email','$this->sex', '$this->birthdate', '$this->phone', '$this->country', '$this->displayname', 'F')") or die(mysql_error());

                $this->addUser;
                $this->addProfile;

                            return true;

            }
            else{

                return false;
            }
        }

        public function checkFields(){
            if(($this->firstname)!="" && ($this->lastname)!="" && ($this->email)!="" && ($this->sex)!="" && 
                ($this->birthdate)!="" &&($this->country)!="" && ($this->handle)!="" && ($this->password)!=""){

                return true;     
            } else {

                return false;
            }

        }

        public function confirmPasswords(){

            if($this->confirm_password1==$this->confirm_password2){

                return true;
            } else {

                return false;
            }
        }

        private $site, $firstname, $lastname, $email,
        $sex, $birthdate, $phone, $country, $displayname, 
        $handle, $password, $salt, $joindate, $confirm_password1, $confirm_password2;

        protected $addUser, $addProfile;

    }
```

Comment: Try adding `console.log(data);` in your success function to see what it sends back.

Comment: @Musa: I'm sorry. Can you explain where I would add this function?

Comment: I tested it as you suggested. Thank you for your helpful suggestion. I have found that the case (data == -4) is not returning for some reason. So it looks like the issue now lies somewhere with the PHP file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. The issue was due to printf() functions that were apart of a few class members in the database class. They were causing an interruption with the function completing and returning the boolean value true or false in registerUser();

Thank you all for your help and assistance. I would give up a vote up, but I don't have enough reputation points. haha.